# Why "permit" in Strong Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How is this:

```
 def model1_params
   params.require(:model1).permit(:key1, :key2) 
 end
```

more secure that this?

```
 def model1_params
   params.permit(:key1, :key2)
 end
```

Why is `require(:model1)` required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really more secure, it's just a way of organizing params into objects.

if you say `params.require(:model).permit(:a)` that's expecting the params to come in as `{ model: { a: <val> } }`. This nested-hash style namespacing is the default for generated scaffolds, but routes work perfectly fine without it (I haven't use `params.require` in a while).

The point of secure params is to prevent you from doing something like `model.update(params)` which is insecure because then clients can update any attibutes they choose, such as id. The `<model>_params` methods used to implement secure params are basically filter functions that return a whitelisted version of the `params` hash.

So you don't need to use `params.require` or `params.permit`, you can write it by scratch if you want:

```
  def whitelisted_params
    params.select { |key| key.in? [:my, :whitelisted, :params] }
  end
```

Comment: rspec requires that. without "require", even with "permit", in a model Rspec won't allow me to update a model is is possible to turn it off?

Comment: @Oodaao RSpec is not inherently tied to Rails. I don't know how to resolve your issue without seeing the code. Maybe post another question.

Answer (score 0):

`params.permit(:key1, :key2)` is not secure. It is because you are directly permitting the params without associating it with an object. 
On the other hand,`params.require(:model1).permit(:key1, :key2)` is more secure because you are binding keys with the object.

Comment: and how's that secure?

Comment: it first check the object & then read the keys . for eg: {user : {name: "Allen"}}, so it will first check the user object & then its key name

Comment: and how's that secure?

Comment: You are not directly accessing the params from the internet. You are whitelisting them.

Comment: and how's that secure?

Comment: For eg. you are saving user info & his address in two different table. User table contains type i.e. admin, customer, etc & address table contains type: primary , secondary, etc. & you are permitting the same field , so value will gets overwriten, In this case , you need to bind this in model to keep your original value in both the table

Comment: it won't, you just add a prefix to them on a client. but we're talking about a single model.